# Reading a project text file windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, file-io

I'm having trouble accessing a text file that is packaged with my Windows Phone 8 app.

Here is the code:

```
var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Data-Test.docx", UriKind.Relative));
if (ResrouceStream != null)
{
    Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream;
    if (myFileStream.CanRead)
    {
        // logiic here
        retrun "Hi";
    }
}
else
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Seems simple but the app always returns "hello". i have placed the file in root and also in assets, changed it to content - copy and do not copy, resource copy and do not copy but always it returns "hello".

Spent several hours on this and all solutions I can find show the solution or very similar above!

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Returns "hello" when I deploy to phone or emulator.
also tried "/Data-Test...", @"\Data-Text..., @/"Data-Test...!

UPDATE 1:

```
         string aReturn = "";
         var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

         //Use this to verify the namespacing of the "Embedded Resource".
         //asm.GetManifestResourceNames()
         //               .ToList()
         //               .ForEach(name => Debug.WriteLine(name));

         var ResourceStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ContosoSocial.Assets.QuizQuestions.QuizQuestions-Test1.docx");

         if (ResourceStream != null) //  <--CHECKED AND DOES NOT EQUAL NULL
         {
             Stream myFileStream = ResourceStream;

             if (myFileStream.CanRead) // <-- CHEACKED AND CAN READ
             {
                 StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);

                 LOGIC & EXCEPTION HERE...?
                 string myLine = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
             }
             else
             {
                 aReturn = "myFileStream.CanRead = true";
             }
         }
         else
         {
             aReturn = "stream equals null";
         }
         Debug.WriteLine(aReturn);
     }
```

The assignment of myFileStream to a StreamReader object is throwing the exception null pointer. I thought I would wrap myFileStream to a StreamReader so I can read a line at a time..? This is my first c# project and I'm unfamiliar with it's syntax and classes.

UPDATE 2:
OK I added...

```
 Debug.WriteLine(aReturn);
```

...following...

```
 string myLine = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
```

...and noticed it was retrieving only the 2 characters 'PK' !
So saved the .docx file as .txt and reinserted adn changed build copy to embedded - do not copy...Happy days it now pulls off the first line in the file.

Thanks  to OmegaMan for your help with this one :-)

Comment: what build action do you have on your file?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml is embedded and do not copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change file type in the project to `Embedded Resource`
2. Extract the resource by working the namespace to its location. Here is an example code where I pull in an XSD:

Code:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// Use this to verify the namespacing of the "Embedded Resource".
//  asm.GetManifestResourceNames()
//     .ToList()
//     .ForEach(name => Debug.WriteLine(name));

var f1 = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("UnitTests.Resources.NexusResponse.xsd");
```

Note this is not tested on WP8, but GetExecutingAssembly is stated to work within .Net. If you get the namespace wrong, uncomment out the code and display or debug to determine the resources and their namespace.

Comment: could you check your syntax in the foreach loop as I'm getting a couple red line errors with this.

Comment: @TripVoltage My bad...thanks for pointing it out. Fixed in example above.

Comment: Thanks so the debugger output is ContosoSocial.g.resources
ContosoSocial.Resources.AppResources.resources
ContosoSocial.QuizQuestions-Test.docx then I assign it like: var ResourceStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ContosoSocial.QuizQuestions.docx"); but it's always null when I check it!

Comment: @TripVoltage yes, you are only interested in the .docx file so that will work.

Comment: scrap that I now works with this one ContosoSocial.Assets.QuizQuestions.QuizQuestions-Test1.docx... Cheers fella many thanks :-)

Comment: Hi I'm assigning: var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); & var ResourceStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ContosoSocial.Assets.QuizQuestions.QuizQuestions-Test1.docx"); & checked ResourceStream variable here and not equal null. OK so now assigned: Stream myFileStream = ResourceStream; & checked if myFileSteam.CanRead - it can. So assigned StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream); so I can read a line ata a time but I get a 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ContosoSocial.DLL here, any ideas what I'm doing worng here!